# Using functions from a package in R

Tags: r, package

I am using a R package Cat

In the help file an example for function **data** uses dataset head

```
data(head)
```

I have my own dataset and I want to try this function data within the package CAT on my dataset **A**

when I try

```
library(cat)
A = read.table("C:/A.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
data(A)
```

I get a warning

```
"Warning message: In data(A) : data set ‘A’ not found*
```

How do I use specific functions that are part of R packages on my dataset and not the examples in those packages>

Comment: You load your data with `read.table` function and you may refer to them simply as `A`. You do not need to use `data` function (which allows you to load data set from a given package, for example `data("iris", package='datasets')`).

Comment: I think you should check if A is in your environment before the `data(A)` part.

Comment: Cenka, I think i explained the problem incorrectly. The function data does not help in loading data. I know the read.table option :-) , the function data does something else and i want to use that function data on my dataset A.

Comment: Seth, how do I add my dataset A to my environment ? so that I can use it with function data, package cat :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @cenka pointed out, when you are loading your own data, you do not need to use the `data()`  function. That is only for loading data from packages. If you want to use functions from a specific package after you install it, be sure to call `library(cat)` to actually load the library into your current R session.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, Cenka Seth I will do that.